# What is the return type of Http.get().catch?

Tags: angular, typescript, exception, rxjs, angular2-observables

I'm currently learning angular 2, taking Deborah Kurata's Pluralsight class (Angular 2: Getting Started). It's great so far, but, for the life of me, I can't seem to discover what the return type  of my `.catch` should be. In her course, and in every example I've found so far, the return type is left blank.

This is what I have:

```
getProducts(): Observable<IProduct[]> {
    return this._http.get("someurl")
        .map {.....}
        .catch(this.handleError);
}

handleError (response: Response) **/*what goes here?*/** {
    // the code in the course says Observable.throw, but chrome is
    // complaining that there is no such function. I have tracked 
    // down "static throw: typeof ErrorObservable.create;" in 
    // Observable.ts but I'm not sure what's going on here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most common return type is an `Observable`.

To be precise, the selector function to the `catch()` operator is defined as:

```
(err: any, caught: Observable): ObservableInput
```

The returned Observable is subscribed using the `subscribeToResult` which supports multiple return types (that's why there's `ObservableInput` and not just `Observable`). Anyway, it's easier to have a look at the examples in the source code that aren't in the online documentation yet where you should be able to understand how it works: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/operator/catch.ts#L8

Or see what `subscribeToResult` supports: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/util/subscribeToResult.ts#L17

Comment: Thanks @martin. Unfortunately the source code doesn't clarify much (for me). But I see the line "export function _catch<T, R>(this: Observable<T>, selector: (err: any, caught: Observable<T>) => ObservableInput<R>): Observable<R> {...}. So, "_catch" (not "catch") is a function that takes "this" (how does that work in TS?) and a selector function. The selector function returns ObservableInput<R>, while _catch itself returns Observable<R>. Which one of those, specifically, is the ".catch" returning? (I also tried to return "Observable", but of course it complained about missing generic type.)

Comment: @emery.noel Can you show the exact code that gives you type errors?